# Using multiple callbacks for Rails (:after_commit)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

Would there be conflicts if I have multiple callbacks of the same nature in Rails? Like several after_commit for the same model?

I guess I can join them into one method, but for readability reasons, I would rather not..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No they will be executed one after another

```
after_commit :callback_one, :callback_two
```

Comment: And they get executed in reverse order, that is `callback_two` first and then `callback_one`

Comment: What if one of them needs` on: :create` while the second doesn't.

Comment: what if one of them has `if: :condition`